# Security Copy of a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow

i need to make a security copy of my site every month. I think It´s possible with Microsoft Flow. Is any way to do this? Just with MS Flow and SharePoint.
Regards!

Comment: what's a "security copy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint online has its own backup plan and it’s not open for end users. If you need a restoration you can always make a service request for this.As for the MS Flow solution, I don't think this is possible at all, Flow has plenty of restrictions for timeout operations and backing up a whole site can be a time consuming task.

So, what are your alternatives? Tools like ShareGate might do the trick, but doesn't seem the way to go for you, as you seem to be looking for a third-party software free answer. With that in mind, try the AdHoc path using the [PnP provisioning service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-provisioning-framework). You can tailor a custom solution for your needs.